# Approach to model 100 aircraft

Tags: modeling

I have a need to create quite a lot of aircraft models which later will be utilized in visual scenes of air traffic simulation.

They don't need to be perfect, but to be acceptable and good for eye from distance.

Not much details expected, but gear, flaps, lights expected.

Also, 3-4 LOD levels required.

I wonder what would be Your approach? I have a collection of fuselage cross-sections

blueprints, which I was thinking to utilize to create quickly 9-10 cross-sections curves and then loft a body, but I never had a good experience with NURBS.

Any thoughts? How would You approach this kind of task?

Appreciate Your help!

Comment: Hello, I'll throw a heads-up : If you want answers on this site you will have to restrict the spectrum of your question to more specific topics and ask things that are not subjective / opinion based. Also it helps if you throw in some of your work / research or what you have tried and explain where it failed.

Comment: Hi, thabks for your input. I thought i already did that. Let me try to elaborate further. Aircraft fuselage main figure is the cylinder, the hardest part of fuselage to model for me is the belly, where wings are attached to the fuselage. One way i thought about it was to use nurbs, in particular, loft. But i didn't like the result, especially the fact of conversion to mesh afterwards and retopo to reduce polygons.